# Install failed without no matching abis on Android L emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop

I use the Intel Atom Image and run on Ubuntu 12.04. Everytime I run the android project with armabi libs, the emulator prints FAILED_INSTALL_NO_MATCHING_ABIS.Anyone can help me?